# mongo replace ObjectId in array with data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have model like this:

```
{
    name: 'John Doe',
    items: [
        { count: 5, item: ObjectId('xxx1') },
        { count: 2, item: ObjectId('xxx2') }
    ]
}
```

`items` field is not required and contains number field and reference to other entity. I would like to replace `item` inside `items` array with data from entity like so:

```
{
    name: 'John Doe',
    items: [
        { count: 5, item: { more: 'data', from: 'other entity' } },
        { count: 2, item: { more: 'data 2', from: 'other entity 2' } }
    ]
}
```

I tried using mongo's aggregate and lookup:

```
Model.aggregate([
   {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'items',
          localField: 'users.items',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'users.items'
        }
   }
]);
```

but that's replacing everything inside items array (loosing field `count`). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: { path: "$items", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: 'items',
         localField: 'items.item',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'items.item'
      }
   },
   { $set: { "items.item": { $arrayElemAt: ["$items.item", 0] } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { _id: "$_id", name: "$name" },
         items: { $push: "$$ROOT.items" }
      }
   },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] } } }
])
```

Comment: seems to work but what if `items` field in users collection is not required? I'm loosing those users who have items = [] (empty array there)

Comment: can't edit.. preserveNullAndEmptyArrays in $unwind seems to solve it